# Is there an xmpp client that can persist chats across page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmpp, chat

We have a book reading application and I have been tasked with implementing basic chat functionality.  We have chosen openfire as the chat server.  My question is, while reading a book, when the user turns the page, this does a complete page refresh.  How can I keep the chat going across those refreshes? I don't want to bump a user and make them rejoin.  Any ideas of the path I should take to implement this? We would in theory like to drop in a client into the page and it works with minimal effort.  Anyways, are their clients that persist across refreshes?

Answer (score 2):

Web pages are stateless. They cannot by themselves propagate data from one load to another. For that, you need to use cookies, and/or server-side sessions. Once you've got a user logged in and a login cookie/session token established, you can SIMULATE the chat being unbroken.

Basically, you keep the state of the chat in the user's session file, and update as necessary. That way, whenever the page is reloaded or they navigate to another page, the chat's state "just follows along", making it appear it was never gone.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX + postate/onhashchange effect for all of the pages on the website. This way the page itself (the view) can change, but the content wrapping around it (header + footer) won't change.